# The bot first joins the voice and then executes the command and then leaves the voice

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to join the voice channel first and then run the command and send a message and then leave the voice channel again but I've failed. I'm still very new, I'm waiting for your suggestions as a resource.

My code:

```
    client.on("message", function (message) {
  if (message.content === "hello"){
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      const connection = DiscordMessage.member.voice.channel.join();
    const channel01 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "838137321169223701");
   channel01.send("hi")
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into your code, I noticed you are missing an actual function to let your bot join the voice chat. What you did was simply call a "const" variable, though never executed it. If you'd like your bot to leave right after the response is sent, that'd make your bot join the call for less than a second, though this is what you can replace your current code with.

```
  client.on("message", function (message) {
    if (message.content === "hello"){
      if (message.member.voice.channel) {

        const VoiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel
        const channel01 = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "849139242478206976");
        
        VoiceChannel.join()
        
        channel01.send("hi").then(setTimeout(function(){
          VoiceChannel.leave()
        }, 2000));

      }
    }
  });
```

This would make your bot join the voice chat, and leave it 2 seconds after, as you can see from the timeout function. If you prefer not to have any timeout, you can simply replace the values after .then with:

```
.then(VoiceChannel.leave());
```

I hope it helped!